# Pass controllers's input value to another page's stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart, controller

**login.dart**

```
class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggleForm;

  const LoginForm(this.toggleForm, {super.key});

  @override
  _LoginFormState createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final TextEditingController _mobileNumberController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(controller: _mobileNumberController,);
  }
}
```

**OTP.dart**

```
class OTPScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String MobileNum;
  const OTPScreen({super.key, required this.MobileNum});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(MobileNum);
  }
}

class HomePageLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        OtherWidget(),
        OTPScreen(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**How to Pass controllers's input value to another stateful widget**

*How to pass `TextFormField(controller: _mobileNumberController,)`  value to the another page's stateful widget*
Solution Please! Is anything missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the value of the **_mobileNumberController** to the OTP screen you can do it in many ways one of them is to access the **value** attribute of the **TextEditingController** and pass it through the constructor of the **OTPScreen** when navigating to it, like below:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
      return OTPScreen(MobileNum: _mobileNumberController.value.toString());
    }));
```